# 403 Woosync + woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, error-403

la pregunta es si alguien ha tenido problemas al instalar el plugin de Woosync con woocommerce, al intalar y hacer la conexión me sale un error 403 que me indica que el servidor me lo bloquea, he colocado las ip del plugin en la lista blanca del servidro, tambien restablecido el htaccess, creando los crom de la documentación, pero sigue lo mismo, tambien me contacté con el proveerdor de hosting y pusieron la ip de woosync pero sigue saliendo igual, si alguien a tenido ese caso agradecería su ayuda de como lo solucionó.

Comment: Hola, como estas?. Para poder ayudar de mejor manera podrias compartir mayor informacion?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Aunque si tiene que ver con programación, al ser código de terceros y no saber exactamente que falla no podemos ayudarte, por favor lee [ask] y de paso haz el [tour], tampoco estaría mal leer como hacer un [example] pues tu pregunta no se adapta a lo requerido por la plataforma.